# how to query value inside of object array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get document that it's 'from' field value in 'from' of 'periods' array.

I've tried followings but it doesn't work. how can i?

```
periods = [{
    from: 333,
    to: 555
},
{
    from: 666,
    to: 777
}]

var eqbookschema = new Schema({
eq_dbId: String,
user_dbId: String,
from: Number,
to: Number,
timestamp: Number,
}, {collection: 'book'});

EQBook = mongoose.model('EQBook', eqbookschema)

EQBook.find({
    eq_dbId: req.body.eq_dbId,
    from: {$in: [periods.from]}
})
```

The query I have tried only returns empty array although existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `periods` is an array of object and you want to find based on `from` field of each element so you need to map it first:

```
let froms = periods.map(val => val.from);
```

Then find with mapped array:

```
EQBook.find({
  eq_dbId: req.body.eq_dbId,
  from: {$in: froms}
})
```

Or just:

```
EQBook.find({
  eq_dbId: req.body.eq_dbId,
  from: {$in: periods.map(val => val.from)}
})
```

Comment: is there no other way using mongoose query?

Comment: What do you mean? It's using mongoose query, just edit the input to filter result.

Comment: using that way, periods not changed?

Comment: Yes, `.map()` doesn't modify the orginal array.

Comment: is there no other way using mongoose operator?

Comment: I think no in this case.

Answer (score 0):

create an array of 'from' values only

```
periodFrom = periods.map((elem)=>elem.from);

EQBook.find(
  {eq_dbId: req.body.eq_dbId,from:{$in:periodFrom}}
)
```

Comment: as you can see in in the model, EQBook has no 'periods' field.

Comment: thank you for your help. you' right, but i can only one accept. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
let froms = periods.map(data => data.from);
EQBook.aggregate([
{
 $match : {'eq_dbId': ObjectId(req.body.eq_dbId),'from':{$in:[periodFrom]}
}
])
```